# SwiftUI Underlined Hyperlinks

Tags: swift, swiftui, hyperlink, localizedstringkey

I am using hyperlinks in SwiftUI which are highlighted, but I also want them to be underlined as well. Is that possible?

```
Text("This [link](https://google.com) goes to google")
```

How can I make the link part underlined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Text - how can I create a hyperlink and underline a weblink in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71541408/20386264)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for link runs in the attributed string and based on their ranges modify the attributes of the main string:

```swift
let baseString = "Hello [World](https://www.google.com) this is [Google](https://www.yahoo.com)"
var text = try! AttributedString(markdown: baseString)
let runsWithLinks = text.runs.filter { run in
    run.link != nil
}

for run in runsWithLinks {
    text[run.range].font = .system(size: 18).monospaced() // extra example
    text[run.range].foregroundColor = .gray               // extra example
    text[run.range].underlineStyle = .init(pattern: .solid, color: .green)
}
```

Previewing the above example yields this result:

[image]

During my testing, using `.underlineColor` had no effect. I'm not sure why.